# Passing an array to the Google maps geocoder to use in an Infowindow (multiple addresses)

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am trying to create map markers on a Google map using the Geocoder feature. I am Geocoding multiple addresses. I can successfully create the markers, but I need to also create an info window for each marker that displays various different information about the property in that location. For example, I have price information which is comma separated in an array. I have passed through the price[i] array, but I cannot manage to retrieve each price and assign it to the correct infowindow. All I get is the last price in the array being assigned to every marker. I'm trying to do it by calling the geocoder using a callback function, as I couldn't directly pass the price array into the geocoder - it came back undefined. Can anyone help?

The address array looks like this [address1,address2,address3]

The price array looks like this   [500000,400000,300000]

```
var addresses   = address.split(','),
    prices      = price.split(',');

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': addresses[i]}, makeCallback(i));
    }

    function makeCallback(addressIndex) {

        var geocodeCallBack = function(results, status) {

            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            } else {
                var point = results[0].geometry.location;

                var i = addressIndex;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    title: "",
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                infowindow.setContent('<p>'+ prices[i] + '</p>');

                //Open the infowindow
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });

                main.setMap(map, point, titles[i], bounds);
            }
        }

    return geocodeCallBack;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the content of the same `infowindow` for each marker, so it's showing the same one (with the last value it was assigned) no matter which marker is clicked.

Move the line `var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();` to right before `infowindow.setContent('<p>'+ prices[i] + '</p>');` and the correct values should appear.

Or, to have a single `InfoWindow` shared across all your markers (and therefore allow only one to be visible at a time):

The problem is that you're setting the content of `infowindow` when the markers are created rather than when they're clicked. Move the `infowindow.setContent('<p>'+ prices[i] + '</p>');` to within the marker click function, right before `infowindow.open(map, this);`. *In this case, keep the `infowindow` declaration where it is.*

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much. I can't believe it was so simple :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm having trouble closing the infowindow's. I want the infowindow that is open to automatically close when another marker is clicked. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yep! I edited my answer to show another way which will only allow a single infowindow, using your `var infowindow...` declaration at the top of the code where you had it.